# How to switch Intellij from 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have installed Intellij Ultimate Edition. When I saw the installation directory I saw that it installed both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Intellij. But, when I start the Intellij launcher and launch Intellij, it launches 64 bit version of Intellij by default. I am not sure how to switch to 32 bit version as I need to run  a 32 bit version for running my programs. Can I know how to switch to 32 bit version. When I click on idea.exe nothing happens. I need to start the Intellij Launcher for launching Intellij which is launching only a 64 bit version. Do I need to change idea.bat file? Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Java used to run IntelliJ does not influence the version IntelliJ uses to run your code.

If you tell IntelliJ to use a 32-bit Java with your project (set up the SDK when prompted) that will be sufficient.  You will not need to change anything to IntelliJ itself.

Comment: I just need to run my project on 32 bit JRE and 32 bit JVM. I dont want to change the SDK version. Is that possible?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what the SDK version is.  You should not concern yourself with what JVM IntelliJ itself uses.  You should only concern yourself with what JVM you tell IntellJ to use with your program.

Comment: I had hit ctrl+Shift+Alt+S which took me to the project configuration where I changed the SDK version. Is that good enough?

Comment: @krish You are the only one who can say.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to switch in 32 bit??

However, as far as I know, When u want to start the 32 bit one, IDEA uses it's own bundled 32 bit JRE. If there is no such one, IDEA tries to find 32 bit JRE in several places on specific order (%IDEA_HOME%, %JDK_HOME%, %JAVA_HOME%). The values in idea.exe.vmoptions are passed to it. So Check your JRE version.

Comment: But how do I launch a 32 bit version of Intellij? My IDEA has got it's own 32 bit JRE